# SVGs in C#, draw multiple complex rectangles

Tags: c#, svg, bitmap

I'm creating a gannt chart to show hundreds of calendars for individual instances of orders, currently using an algorithm to draw lines and rectangles to create a grid, the problem is I'm the bitmaps are becoming far to large to draw, taking up ram, I've tried multiple different methods including drawing the bitmaps at half size and scaling them up (comes out horribly fuzzy) and still to large.

I want to be able to draw SVGs as I figure for something that draws large simple shapes should reduce the size dramatically compared to bitmaps.

the problem is I cant find anything on msdn that includes any sort of c# library for drawing svgs and I dont want to use external code.

Do I need to create It in XAML or is there a library similar to how bitmaps are drawn ? 
[image: current bitmap version, either going out of bounds on the max size or just freezing because system is out of memory]

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms = GDI / GDI+

WPF/XAML = DirectX (where possible)

Best bet is to go with WPF/XAML which supports scalable vector graphics (not the same as the .svg file format)

You will need 3rd party code to do SVG in WinForms.

---

If you are sticking with WinForms, then bitmapping is the only way this can be achieved really. Take a look at [PixelFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - you might be able to reduce the size of your bitmap in memory by using a format which requires fewer bits-per-pixel for example.

Comment: Ive tried everything with bitmaps to reduce size, but to change pixel format, you cant use drawing because Indexed pixel formats are not allowed from what I can see which would have been the smaller ones, I tried drawing the image in a smaller scale and then scaling up the lower quality image that didnt work either and for some reason I cant understand when a bitmap is zoomed in it blurs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use external tools or SVGs. With a bit of simple math you can easily just render the necessary parts you want to display. All you need is to know the grid size, the range of dates and the range of line-items that are visible in your view. Let's call them:

```
DateTime dispStartDate;
DateTime dispEndDate;
int dispStartItem;
int dispEndItem;
int GridSize = 10; //nifty if you'd like a magnification factor
```

Let's also say you have a class for a Gantt chart item:

```
class gItem
{
    DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
    DateTime EndDate{ get; set; }
    int LineNumber{ get; set; }
    int Length { get { return EndDate - StartDate; } }
    //some other code and stuff you'd like to add
}
```

Now you need a list containing all of your Gantt chart entries:

```
List<gItem> GanttItems;
```

By now you should have assigned values to each of the above variables, now it's time to generate a list of rectangles that would be visible in the view and draw them:

```
List<Rectangle> EntryRects = new List<Rectangle>();

void UpdateDisplayBounds()
{    
    foreach(gItem gEntry in GanttItems)
    {
        if(gEntry.StartDate < dispEndDate && gEntry.EndDate > dispStartDate
           && gEntry.LineNumber >= dispStartItem && gEntry.LineNumber <= dispEndItem)
        {
            int x = (gEntry.StartDate - dispStartDate) * GridSize;
            int y = (gEntry.LineNumber - dispStartItem) * GridSize;
            int width = gEntry.Length * GridSize;
            int height = GridSize;
            EntryRects.Add(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }    
}
```

Now you have a list of rectangles only within the display bounds which you can render. So let's draw:

```
void DrawRectangles(Graphics canvas)//use a picturebox's graphics handler or something for the canvas
{
    canvas.Clear(this.BackColor);
    using(SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue)) //Choose your color
    {
        foreach(Rectangle r in EntryRects)
        {
            canvas.FillRectangle(b, r);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code should get you started. With this you have a list of rectangles that you render on request and the only image taking space in memory is the currently displayed one.

Comment: Your Gannt list is literally what I have currently, Im using math to draw my bitmaps currently in a very similar fashion, I will give this method a try. Thanks